# Copy of reference does not change main reference

Tags: c#

Let i have basic implementation of ListNode class

```
public class ListNode
{
    public int val;
    public ListNode next;
    public ListNode(int val = 0, ListNode next = null)
    {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

I wrote a simple function that is creating some kind of linked list

```
    public static ListNode CreateList(int[] array)
    {
        int i = 0;

        var root = new ListNode();

        var temp = root;

        while (i < array.Length)
        {
            while (temp.next != null)
                temp = temp.next;

            temp.next = new ListNode(array[i]);
            i++;
        }

        return root;
    }
```

In this function line var temp = root; making new variable that point in the same place as root reference. Then some manipulation happens like

```
while (temp.next != null)
    temp = temp.next;
```

manipulation with temp object does not change anything in root object.

Why then

```
var listNode1 = new ListNode(1);
var listNode2 = listNode1;
listNode2.val = 2;
Console.WriteLine(listNode1.val);
```

`istNode2.val = 2;` change `listNode1` ?

In both cases there are manipulation with local variables but in first case it is not changing root.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Note that `temp = temp.next` only changes the value of a *local* variable though, so that statement in itself won't change any objects. It's not clear what you'd expect it to change. The simpler you can make the [mcve], the better - I expect you *can* demonstrate the problem without even using any loops...

Comment: temp and root are both local variables, that initially both refer to the same object. Changing one will not change the other. There are [reference variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/declarations#reference-variables) that could be used that way, but I would be careful since these could impact readability of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because c# uses references, so:

```
var root = new Anything() -> root refer to mem[123]
var temp = root -> temp refer to mem[123]
temp = temp.next; -> temp refer to mem[321] and root still points to mem[123]
```

`root` was never updated neither data in `mem[123]`

Comment: I would avoid using the word "pointer" here when that has a very specific meaning within C#, which *isn't* what you're talking about here.

Comment: @JonSkeet that's true, I'm bit short with proper terminology in this case, what term would u use?

Comment: @JonSkeet ohh reference

Comment: @JanKocev Why temp is not refer to mem[321] after you did temp = temp.next; ?

Comment: @Test123Test234 temp refer to mem[321]

Comment: @JanKocev, Sorry i mean root. Why root is not refer to mem[321] after you did temp = temp.next; ? because temp was pointing to the root?

Comment: @Test123Test234 because even if both refers to same data, they are two variables, you just changed what data are they referring to

Comment: @Test123Test234 if two variables refers to same data and u modify the data, both variables refers to same modified data. If u change what one of the variables is referring to, the second one is not effected at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
var listNode1 = new ListNode(1); // listNode1 refer to mem[A] where ListNode is stored
var listNode2 = listNode1; // listNode2 and listnode1 refers to mem[A]
listNode2.val = 2; // ListNode in mem[A] is set to 2
Console.WriteLine(listNode1.val); // value of ListNode in mem[A] is 2
```

Both vars points to same memory data so if you edit those data both vars will refer to edited data.

```
public static ListNode CreateList(int[] array)
{
    int i = 0;

    var root = new ListNode(); // root refers to mem[A] where ListNode is stored

    var temp = root; // temp and root refers to mem[A]

    while (i < array.Length)
    {
        while (temp.next != null) // for first iteration temp refers to mem[A] temp.next to mem[B]
            temp = temp.next; // temp refers to mem[B] root still to mem[A] 

        temp.next = new ListNode(array[i]);
        i++;
    }

    return root;
}
```

In this case data in mem[A] are updated if in first iteration `temp.next = new ListNode(array[i]);` is called. So if it was called, `root.next` should not be null and should point to mem[B].